# AWS StepFunctions Task state gets cancelled when tearing down a Google Cloud cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am using AWS StepFunctions to carry out several tasks on the Google Cloud side - creating a Dataproc cluster, submitting a task to it, and then tearing it down (each of which have their own Task state, as well as "poller" tasks that check when the jobs have been finished in order to move onto the next Task).

The issue is, for tearing down the cluster, the Task goes into the "cancelled" (gray) status instead of "in progress", followed by the poller Task. Once the cluster deletion lambda function executes the cluster deletion method, it should move on to the poller Task.

Here is a look at the **cluster deletion lambda function**:

```
from pprint import pprint
from google.cloud import storage
import googleapiclient.discovery
from rkstr8.cloud.google import GoogleCloudLambdaAuth
import time

def handler(event, context):

    creds = event['GCP_creds']
    GoogleCloudLambdaAuth(creds).configure_google_creds()

    dataproc = googleapiclient.discovery.build('dataproc', 'v1')
    project_id = event['gcp-administrative']['project']
    zone = event['gcp-administrative']['zone']
    try:
        region_as_list = zone.split('-')[:-1]
        region = '-'.join(region_as_list)
    except (AttributeError, IndexError, ValueError):
        raise ValueError('Invalid zone provided, please check your input.')
    cluster = event['dataproc-administrative']['cluster_name']

    print('Tearing down cluster...')
    request = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().delete(
        projectId=project_id,
        region=region,
        clusterName=cluster)

    time.sleep(30)

    result = request.execute()

    return result
```

Here is what the relevant part of the state machine building code looks like:

```
    dproc_submit_state = AsyncPoller(
                    stats_path=DPROC_SUBMIT_POLLER_STATUS_PATH,
                    async_task=Task(
                        name=DPROC_SUBMIT,
                        resource=DPROC_SUBMIT_ARN_VAR,
                        input_path=DPROC_SUBMIT_INPUT_PATH,
                        result_path=DPROC_SUBMIT_RESULT_PATH,
                        next=DPROC_SUBMIT_POLLER
                    ),
                    pollr_task=Task(
                        name=DPROC_SUBMIT_POLLER,
                        resource=DPROC_SUBMIT_POLLER_ARN_VAR,
                        input_path=DPROC_SUBMIT_RESULT_PATH,
                        result_path=DPROC_SUBMIT_POLLER_STATUS_PATH
                    ),
                    faild_task=Fail(
                        name='HailScriptFailed'
                    ),
                    succd_task=DPROC_DELETE,
                    pollr_wait_time=self.conf["POLLER_WAIT_TIME"]
                    ).states()
    dproc_delete_state = AsyncPoller(
                    stats_path=DPROC_DELETE_POLLER_STATUS_PATH,
                    async_task=Task(
                        name=DPROC_DELETE,
                        resource=DPROC_DELETE_ARN_VAR,
                        input_path=DPROC_DELETE_INPUT_PATH,
                        result_path=DPROC_DELETE_RESULT_PATH,
                        next=DPROC_DELETE_POLLER
                    ),
                    pollr_task=Task(
                        name=DPROC_DELETE_POLLER,
                        resource=DPROC_DELETE_POLLER_ARN_VAR,
                        input_path=DPROC_DELETE_RESULT_PATH,
                        result_path=DPROC_DELETE_POLLER_STATUS_PATH
                    ),
                    faild_task=Fail(
                        name='ClusterDeleteFailed'
                    ),
                    succd_task='PipelineSucceeded',
                    pollr_wait_time=self.conf["POLLER_WAIT_TIME"]
                    ).states()
```

Here is what the state machine looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sleeping for 30 seconds between creating a request and executing it?

The default timeout for lambda is 3 seconds. My guess is that your lambda is just timing out.